# The datepicker in pop-up window - can not select the date, because page is scrolling to natural position

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have problem... I try to use datepicker in input, and there they work well (run, display). But there is problem when I try to select the date. Then page is scroll to normall position when it is opening.

Example with video:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToQOe.jpg

I can not do the JSFiddle of it, because pop-up window is included in theme....

Link to my website:

Somone could help me?

//Edit1 I found this solution:

[jQuery UI datepicker causes screen to scroll to the top after selecting a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447348/jquery-ui-datepicker-causes-screen-to-scroll-to-the-top-after-selecting-a-date)

But this doesnt work...

even when link is "javascript:;"

//Edit 2: I fount problem why... and this works almost well:

(Script include)

But now problem is that the datepicker showing up somwhere but not under the input:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlpHc.png

How can I force to display above or under the input?

Answer (score 0):

I fount solution which work for me... Problem was because datepicker is appending to body... no where is the input. We have to append the datepicker after the input (must be in pop-up window where you want to use it).

This code worked for me that set the datepicker under the input and you can select without problem:

```
$("input").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        $(input).after($(input).datepicker('widget'));

         setTimeout(function () {
            inst.dpDiv.css({
                top: 'auto',
                left: 'auto'
            });
        }, 0);

        }});
```

I hope it will help in future someone!